# Problem with creating an table with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm learning how to make ORM databases in Java. But after I created the table model, it gives me an error.

I want to combine minecraft api with orm database for easily store data of the players(his modified items data) and now i creating my 'magical storage' where players can store his items.

Models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "storage_id")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)
    private UUID storageId;

    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserStorage userStorage;

    public UserStorage getUserStorage() {
        return userStorage;
    }

    public void setUserStorage(UserStorage userStorage) {
        this.userStorage = userStorage;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(UUID uuid, String username, UUID storageId) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.username = username;
        this.storageId = storageId;
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    public void setUUID(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public UUID getStorageId() {
        return storageId;
    }

    public void setStorageId(UUID storageId) {
        this.storageId = storageId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User " +
                "[uuid = \"" +
                this.uuid.toString() +
                "\", username = \"" +
                this.username +
                "\", storageId = " +
                this.storageId +
                "]";
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class RawItem {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "storage_id", nullable = false)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)
    private UUID storageId;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserStorage userStorage;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "data", length = 4096)
    private String data;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public JSONObject getData() throws ParseException {
        return (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(this.data);
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        this.data = data.toJSONString();
    }


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserStorage getUserStorage() {
        return userStorage;
    }

    public void setUserStorage(UserStorage userStorage) {
        this.userStorage = userStorage;
    }

    public UUID getStorageId() {
        return storageId;
    }

    public void setStorageId(UUID storageId) {
        this.storageId = storageId;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_storage")
public class UserStorage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "slots_count")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.BIGINT)
    private Integer slotsCount;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userStorage", orphanRemoval = true)
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getSlotsCount() {
        return slotsCount;
    }

    public void setSlotsCount(Integer slotsCount) {
        this.slotsCount = slotsCount;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userStorage", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RawItem> rawItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<RawItem> getRawItems() {
        return rawItems;
    }

    public void setRawItems(List<RawItem> rawItems) {
        this.rawItems = rawItems;
    }

    public UserStorage() {}

    public UserStorage(Integer slotsCount) {
        this.slotsCount = slotsCount;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : user_storage
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:364) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:176) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:144) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:128) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:254) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.buildSessionFactory(MetadataImpl.java:186) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Is there a *caused by*  in the stactrace?

Comment: probably `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)` together with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`